# Jquery display a div onclick of submit

Tags: jquery

When i click a button,i've to show a div with contents

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="but">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JS**

```
$("#but").click(function () {
    alert("h");
    $(this).html('<div>test</div>');​
});
```

But this is not working​

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to add `<div>` to your DOM then use this:

```
$("#but").click(function() {
    $("<div>test</div>").appendTo("body");
});
```

Note: instead of `body` you may use any other container.

If you need to replace button with `<div>` block then use `replaceWith`:

```
$("#but").click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<div>test</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

input is not `container` use `after` or `before`.

```
$("#but").click(function () {
    $(this).after('<div>test</div>');
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/5pt5r/](http://jsfiddle.net/5pt5r/)

Answer (score 0):

you have taken input button of submit type which causes postback. So when you try to attempt any jquery then it works but page is posted back so it seem that it is not working . Use input type='button' then it will work.